# What are the methods of heat transfer on a tubular heat pipe and how is its thermal circuit?

Tags: heat

I would like to know how many heat transfer methods are on a tubular heat pipe and the configuration of its thermal circuit.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Space Exploration!  It sounds like you have an interesting question  but it needs some clarification.  Could you a) show what you have already achieved (e.g. what heat pipe applications you already know with examples of the application, scale and ideally a picture) and b) try to make the question more specific (it might help to write the question in terms of the problem you want to solve)

Comment: For the pipe you consider, evaluate conduction, convection and radiation.

Comment: Note, we have also an https://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Also please [edit] to show *relevance to space exploration*